# Bot Framework ErrorResponseException: "The bot referenced by the 'from' field is unrecognized"

Tags: botframework, telegram-bot

My bot in Telegram **worked fine for many months**, and suddenly...

```
ErrorResponseException: "The bot referenced by the 'from' field is unrecognized"
```

It throws each time when my bot tries to reply to an incoming message.

The `from` field didn't change. The bot id in Telegram can't change.

I checked: the bot HTTP Request is sent with the correct bot id in the `from.id` field.

I use `Microsoft.Bot.Builder v3.15.3` Nuget package

Answer (score 0):

### I had to renew the Telegram Bot access token

I went to `@BotFather` in Telegram and invoked the `/revoke` command to change the token to access HTTP API.

Then I went to my Functions bot in the Azure Portal, and on Channels section clicked on "Edit" on my Telegram bot. I pasted the new Access token, saved, and it works again!

### What caused it?

Looks like the token somehow expired. I created my bot 355 days ago (Dec 14, 2017), and haven't changed the token since then.

But I'm not sure if it's the reason.

[See how similar solution helped for Facebook bot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4898).

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue for the Skype for Business channel. I haven't changed the from.id but the bot stoped to work correct. I seems Microsoft started to validate this field and before I had incorrect value of this one.

I just went throught the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview) one more time and saw my mistake:

```
"from": {
  "id": "sip:user@contoso.com",
  "name": "Contoso User"
}
```